# jQuery - $.each find if first run of $.each

Tags: jquery, each

I am not sure if I can do this or not: I need to know how to find out if the json `$.each` is running for the first time.

So say I have 14 items in the JSON the `$.each` goes though 14 times I want to do something different to the first time the `$.each` run.

For example, say the first return is the letter **A**, and in the array we have **A,B,C,D,E,F**.

I want to bold the **A** but none of the others.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The callback function for [`$.each` gets the index](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) as its first parameter:

```
$.each(collection, function(index, value) {
    // index will be zero on the first one
});
```

Comment: +1 heh.  i was still typing and '2 new answers' came in.  : )

Comment: Like mu said, however when using Associative Arrays, the key is the association (could be any text).

Comment: +1 Perfect! It also works without a collection variable:
$.each(function(index, value) { ...}